# Ударение в слове "послушаться"

Tags: фонетика

Несколько раз слышала, как люди говорят "послушАться" в значении "слушаться" или "находиться в послушании", "подчиняться".
Например: "он послушАлся родителям", в смысле "он подчинялся родителям, слушался их". Может быть, это какая-то устаревшая форма от слова "послушник"?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, оборот "послушаться родителям" неверный. Есть слово "слушаться" с ударением на У - "слушаться родителей". Но "совершать послушАние в монастыре".

Comment: спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь (негде сейчас уточнить) в церковном контексте (т.е. в значении "быть в послушании") именно послуш**а**ться. Но вот насколько возможно "послушаться (кому?)" - не могу сказать. И уж вряд ли родителям, если это только не молитвенный текст. 
И конечно же, п**о**слушник (ударение - опять-таки по церковным правилам) от послушаться, послушание, а не наоборот.

Comment: У Розенталя нашла  послушный чему? И пример из Пушкина - Он пел любовь, любви послушный. Тот, кто послушается - послушный? Тогда управление послушаться кому? - тоже верное.

Comment: Да я тоже не отвергал такую возможность. 
Но с Пушкиным - непонятно. Там может быть послушный и чему/кому, и чего/кого. Вот если бы речь шла о вариантах выбора между дательным и винительным, то да. Но у нас-то выбирать приходится между дательным и родительным...

А из Розенталя хотелось бы контекст. Само-то по себе "послушный чему", разумеется, никаких возражений не вызывает. Но насколько справедливо переносить это на управление глагола "послушаться" - не знаю. Короче, тут разбираться надо.

Comment: спасибо :)